# What's the best method to get a fix into a feature branch before it's been merged into master?

Tags: git, merge

Say I have a branch `feature_branch` off of `master`. While working on it, I realize that I need to make a fix on master.

I make a new branch `fix_branch` off of `master`. It's a small fix, so let's keep the reviews small, right? I submit a PR and wait for a code review of `fix_branch`. Meanwhile, I want fold in the changes in `fix_branch` into `feature_branch` so I can keep working.

What's the best way to avoid merge conflicts and confusing git history, given that:

- I'm confident `fix_branch` won't be abandoned
- There might be small changes to `fix_branch` before it's accepted
- In our org, we usually rebase master into feature branches before merging

Comment: Merge `fix_branch` into `feature_branch`. When `feature_branch` is rebased, the merge commit should then be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Meanwhile, I want fold in the changes in fix_branch into feature_branch so I can keep working

Simply rebase your `feature_branch` on top of `fix_branch`, and continue working from there.

Once `fix_branch` is merged into `upstream/master`, rebase `feature_branch` on top of `upstream/master` (which now includes `fix_branch`), then force push.
That will update your original PR, and won't duplicate `fix_branch` commits.

Comment: Makes sense to me except for "original PR", since the only PR i have is for `fix_branch` -- but I'm assuming that you thought I had two PR's, one for `feature_branch` and one for `fix_branch`?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that force pushing an existing PR will update it